# Gatsby build webpack fail with stylis

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, gatsby, stylish

When I run gatsby build I get this error:

```
failed Building static HTML for pages - 10.179s

 ERROR #95313 

Building static HTML failed

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html


  343 |         for (c = []; b < a; ++b) {
  344 |           for (var n = 0; n < m; ++n) {
> 345 |             c[v++] = Z(d[n] + ' ', h[b], e).trim();
      | ^
  346 |           }
  347 |         }
  348 | 


  WebpackError: The module '/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node'
  
  - stylis.esm.js:345 
    node_modules/@emotion/stylis/dist/stylis.esm.js:345:1
  
  - stylis.esm.js:151 
    node_modules/@emotion/stylis/dist/stylis.esm.js:151:1
  
  - stylis.esm.js:175 
    node_modules/@emotion/stylis/dist/stylis.esm.js:175:1
  
  - stylis.esm.js:286 
    node_modules/@emotion/stylis/dist/stylis.esm.js:286:1
  
  - stylis.esm.js:151 
    node_modules/@emotion/stylis/dist/stylis.esm.js:151:1
  
  - stylis.esm.js:175 
    node_modules/@emotion/stylis/dist/stylis.esm.js:175:1
  
  - stylis.esm.js:286 
    node_modules/@emotion/stylis/dist/stylis.esm.js:286:1
  
  - stylis.esm.js:151
```

How to solve? When run gatsby develop there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

Update gatsby-config.js to contain the plugin gatsby-plugin-emotion:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-emotion`,
  ],
}
```

This needs a restart of the gatsby development process.

Comment: Thanks for reply! But this not work I am not use that plugin. How to solve?

Comment: You solve by installing the plugin and updating the configuration! Its a webpack error..

Comment: Thanks for reply! I have try add to config but it still give error!

Answer (score 0):

Add this snippet in the `gatsby-node.js`:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
          rules: [
          {
            test: /canvas/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
         ],
      },
    })
  } 
}
```

There's a package that is trying to access [global objects such as `window` or `document` in your SSR (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) where obviously is not defined (it even exist) because `gatsby-build` occurs in the Node server while `gatsby develop` occurs in the browser-side, where the `window` exists and the compilation time. With the snippet above, you are adding a `null` loader to the offending module when webpack transpile the code.

The rule test is a regular expression (hence the braces, `/`) that matches the folder name inside `node_modules`. The output error shows a `canvas` issue but you may need to change it to `/stylis/`

Comment: Thanks for reply! Will this cause any issue with my current website - or it just solve the package problem?

Comment: It's just to solve the package interpolation problem. However, as I said, you may need to use `test: /stylis/,`. Take a look at the provided link, it's a common issue when dealing with third-party modules that use the `window` for their stuff.

Comment: Thanks for reply! The link say it will remove the package - so will this cause error if I remove `/canvas/`?

Comment: It won't remove anything. It just adds a null loader to the offending module.

Comment: Thanks for reply! So it just load up null when there the error is display?

Comment: The error comes because your package (`stylis`, `canvas`, or something that they use) is using `window` to make their stuff. Since your `gatsby build` occurs in the server, it breaks the code because there is no `window`. With the snippet above, you are bypassing this limitation, adding a `null` loader to webpack's configuration for the package that matches the regular expression.

Comment: So this mean the package is deactivate?

Comment: Read the docs, please. This means that you are telling webpack to add a `null` loader in its transpilation to avoid the SSR of this dependency.